# R igraph: Color nodes by degree?

Tags: r, attributes, igraph

```
# Erdos
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
g <- erdos.renyi.game(100, 1/100)
V(g)$size<-seq(0.05,5,0.05)
betweenness(g)

# Draw nodes and save positions
locs <- layout.fruchterman.reingold(g)
plot(g, 
     layout=locs, 
     vertex.label=NA, 
     main="Original",
     vertex.color=degree(g))
g

vertex.color=degree(g)
```

did not work. Could anyone tell me how to color the vertices by "degree"?
Red (high value) to blue (low value) would be perfect.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean it does not work, as your plot does have different colours by degree?

Comment: If you want to have the colours from blue to red, just define your own colour scheme: eg. `d=degree(g); cols=setNames(colorRampPalette(c("blue", "red"))(length(unique(d))), unique(d))` and then set the colours using `vertex.color=cols[degree(g)]`. However, there may not be enough range in the colours here: `plot(1:6, col=cols, pch=16, cex=3)`, but just change the `cols` vector to suit.

Comment: That already helped. But it looks like that the biggest values are shown with transparent background. everything else is well scaled from red to blue..

Comment: yes, sorry... use `cols=setNames(colorRampPalette(c("blue", "red"))(length(unique(d))), sort(unique(d)))` to order from zero to upper limit, and the degrees to character `vertex.color=cols[as.character(degree(g))]`

Comment: gives "Error in seq.int(0, 1, length.out = n) : 
  'length.out' must be a non-negative number
In addition: Warning message:
In .approxfun(x, y, v, method, yleft, yright, f) : "
  NAs introduced by coercion". cols[as.character(degree(g))] Looks like: <NA> <NA> <NA> NA NA NA ...

Comment: Works as expected for your example: `d=degree(g) ;
cols=setNames(colorRampPalette(c("blue", "red"))(length(unique(d))), sort(unique(d))) ; plot(g,      layout=locs,      vertex.label=NA,      main="Original",      vertex.color=cols[as.character(degree(g))])`. If you still can't get it to work can you edit your question to show exactly what code oyu are using please.

Answer (score 0):

A solution I found is to create a new color vector with the grey color R provides us with `colors()[]`. If you check `colors()[]` in your terminal, you can see the full list of colors that are readable by the `plot.igraph()` function.

You first charge your data (graph, etc.) :

```
edgelist <- read.csv(...)
graph <- make_graph_from_data(edgelist)
```

Then you create a vector of colors that corresponds to the length of your vertices list :

```
length(V(g)) # with a length of X vertices :

colors <- c(paste0(rep("grey",X),seq(X,1)))
```

Finally, you plot it with the attribute `vertex.color` :

```
  plot(g,vertex.color=colors[degree(graph)])
```

However, one can only use this little trick for graph with less than 100 values in `degree(graph)`...