# R: Assigning Colors to a Graph

Tags: r, data-visualization, igraph, data-manipulation

I am working with the R programming language.

I have the following graph:

```
library(igraph)
library(dplyr)

#create file from which to sample from
x5 <- sample(1:100, 1000, replace=T)
#convert to data frame
x5 = as.data.frame(x5)

#create first file (take a random sample from the created file)
a = sample_n(x5, 900)
#create second file (take a random sample from the created file)
b = sample_n(x5, 900)

#combine
c = cbind(a,b)
#create dataframe
c = data.frame(c)
#rename column names
colnames(c) <- c("a","b")

graph <- graph.data.frame(c, directed=F)
graph <- simplify(graph)

plot(graph)
```

[image]

For each of these nodes in this graph, I have a "value" corresponding to node:

```
length = length(unique(cbind(c(c$a, c$b))))
values = data.frame(node = unique(cbind(c(c$a, c$b))), value = rnorm(length, 200, 10 ))
```

Here is what I have tried so far ([Is there an easy way to color network nodes by degree in igraph for R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66440964/is-there-an-easy-way-to-color-network-nodes-by-degree-in-igraph-for-r)):

```
uni_all <- seq(min(values$value), max(values$value))
colors <- data.frame(color = heat.colors(length(uni_all), rev = T), levels = uni_all)
V(graph)$color <- colors$color[match(V(graph), colors$levels)]

plot(graph)
```

But this is producing a colorless graph:

[image]

**Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong and how I can fix this?**

Thanks!

Comment: Than you so much! I tried to use this code but the colors don't have the same "heat scale" anymore. Is there a way to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: In the post I linked (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66440964/is-there-an-easy-way-to-color-network-nodes-by-degree-in-igraph-for-r), the colors were assigned using "heat colors": https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1HIY.png . Is it possible to change this scale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure the scores in 'values' are in the same order as the vertices in  'graph'. The names of the vertices are stored in V(graph)$name as a vector of strings.

```
values<- values[match(V(graph)$name, values$node), 'value']
```

I suggest using the colorRamp function, so you can define your own color palette.

```
Col_Pal <- colorRamp(c('red','orange','yellow'))
```

The colorRamp function maps values within the interval [0,1] to colors. We will therefore need to normalize the values in 'values' to this range.

```
values<- (values-min(values))/diff(range(values))
```

Extract the colors for the nodes from the color palette based on the values specified in the vector 'values'.

```
Col_Nodes<- rgb(Col_Pal(values), max=255)
```

Assign the colors to the vertices of 'graph', storing them as the attribute 'col'.

```
V(graph)$col<- Col_Nodes
```

Plot the graph.

```
plot(graph, vertex.color = V(graph)$col)
```